# Wordpress: Stripos function won't work on a curl result

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to use stripos on a curl result to check for a specific word. When I upload this code in my functions.php file, my wordpress website breaks down.

```
<?php
//create cURL connection
$curl_connection = 
curl_init("https://www.mywebsite2.com/{$info}");

//set options 

curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, 
  "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.1)");
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($curl_connection, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);


//perform our request
$result = curl_exec($curl_connection);



//close the connection
curl_close($curl_connection);


$start = strpos($result, 'info1 ');

$end = strpos($result, 'end', $start);

$length = $end-$start;

$result = substr($result, $start, $length);

return $result;

//**************************************************
// Check a word then display 'YES' on my Wordpress website

 if ( (stripos($result,'legend')!== false) {
  echo 'YES';
  }

?>
```

The problem seems to come from the stripos function.

Comment: When you use `ini_set('display_errors', 1); ini_set('display_startup_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` at the top of the php file .. What does it display?

Comment: When I use it in the functions.php file, the wordpress site is still down.
If i delete:

     if ( (stripos($result,'legend')!== false) {
      echo 'YES';
      }

It works again.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is incorrect --  You have one to many `(` and you are getting a `cannot use [] for reading` error.

This is the correct syntax:

```
if (stripos($result,'legend')!== false) {
  echo 'YES';
}
```

Notice the removal of the `(` from `if ( (stripos`